# Show typescript method return values when using interface

Tags: typescript, class, tooltip

I am writing a class and am trying to get return values in the tooltip.

```ts
import firebase from "../firebase/init";
import { DonationInterface } from "../interfaces/donation";

export class Donations {
  donationsRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;

  // Initialize collection reference
  constructor(_business_id: string) {
    this.donationsRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`business/${_business_id}/list`);
  }
  /**
   * Get a list of all current donations
   *
   * @returns {DonationInterface[]} Array of all donations of initialized business
   * @example
   *     const donations = Donations.list(); // => [item, item, item]
   */
  async list(): Promise<DonationInterface[]> {
    const snap: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot =
      await this.donationsRef.get();

    const docDataArray: DonationInterface[] = snap.docs.map(
      (doc: firebase.firestore.DocumentData) => {
        return doc.data();
      }
    );

    return docDataArray;
  }

 
}
```

I can only manage to show specific values in the tooltip when I manually re-create the return object with types for each value. If I just return docDataArray, the tooltip only shows the type of Promise<DonationInterface[]>.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since `Donations.list()` is async `Promise<DonationInterface[]>` _is_ its return value. Why are you expecting something different?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is documenting your function like it's returning an array: `@returns {DonationInterface[]}`. That's incorrect. If you try and use the function like this: `Donations.list().foreach(...)` you'll get an error.

Comment: @lbsn I think I might still be a little confused by TS but I'd expect the tooltip to show the internals of _DonationInterface_. So along the lines of `Promise<{name: string, description: string }[]>`. Regarding your second comment; What would be the correct way to document the return value if it is a promise that resolves to an array?

Comment: @lbsn Oh, I guess it would be `@returns {Promise<DonationInterface[]>}`?

Comment: Yes that's the reccomended way (assuming you're using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-async.html). There's also a @async tag). What you call "tooltip" is a feature of your IDE (Intellisense) and shows the signature of the function, so its params and return types. If you call your function like this: `Donations.list().then(items => { item.foreach(item => ...) })` you'll find that `items` has type `DonationInterface[]` and `item` has type `DonationInterface`. So Intellisense is still aware of your function implementation.

Comment: @lbsn Ah, I see. Thank you for the explanation. Is there any way to have Intellisense show the internal types of the interface?